# Swift 2.1 - Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I am having errors with the following code, how do I fix this?

'Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled'

```
 let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection() // - Error Here

        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Reachable via WiFi", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Reachable via Cellular", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Not Reachable", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        reachability.startNotifier() // - Error Here

    }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at "Example - closures" on https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift ?

Comment: @Leo Dabus Could you update the following code in this question thanks, getting errors at the moment.

Comment: @GurvierSinghDhillon try reading first the link Martin R just posted for you

Comment: @Mark R I can get the method working with the link you provided, however what I want to achieve here is to display an AlertController whether their is an internet connection or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [example](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift), you need to wrap the call with `try`.

```
let reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
```

Swift's try/catch system is designed to be clear to developers, which means you need to mark any methods that can throw using the try keyword.

When a function throws an error, it changes the flow of your program, so it’s important that you can quickly identify places in your code that can throw errors. To identify these places in your code, write the try keyword—or the `try?` or `try!` variation—before a piece of code that calls a function, method, or initializer that can throw an error.

You can read more at Apple reference [site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).